# Not able to print the content of a file in perl CGI

Tags: perl, file, cgi, file-handling

I want to print the content of a file line by line in a webpage 
Here is my code which is refusing to work.

```
open(CNF, '<G:\automation_managment\".$n."\config.txt') or die "cant open";
my @cnf=<CNF>;
close(CNF);
my $i= 0;
print "your city, $cnf[$i]"; 
$i++;
print "your age, $cnf[$i]"; 
$i++;
print "your grade, $cnf[$i]"; 
$i++;
print "your phone number, $cnf[$i]"; 
$i++;
print "your email id, $cnf[$i]";
```

Is there a error in open command ? 
It works fine with a absolute path. But not with a variable in path

Comment: Since you are doing "or die" there, you are the one who should know  best about possible errors.

Comment: As a hint: you should use 'or die "cant open: $!";' to get the error message.  And your $n isn't evaluated since you use single quotes.

Comment: The problem is $n is not evaluating even though I have used double quotes and I'm not able to get the die message either.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are sharing the complete code: where do you set $n and perhaps "use warnings;" and "use strict;" give you some more hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
open(CNF, '<G:\automation_managment\".$n."\config.txt') or die "cant open";
```

by:

```
open(CNF, '<G:\automation_managment\'.$n.'\config.txt') or die "cant open";
```

Note the single quotes instead of double.

Moreover you could use forward slashes instead of backward:

```
open(my $fh, '<', 'G:/automation_managment/'.$n.'/config.txt') or die "cant open"
```

Comment: having no luck with this, it prints Backslash found where operator expected at test.pl line 28, near "'<G:\automati
n_managment\'.$n.'\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
Unquoted string "config" may clash with future reserved word at test.pl line 28

syntax error at test.pl line 28, near "'<G:\automation_managment\'.$n.'\"
Bad name after txt' at test.pl line 28.

Comment: I'd suggest sprintf('<G:\automation_managment\%s\config.txt', $n); to avoid the '\' escaping and get the evaluation.

Comment: the reasons for my downvote were the 2 arg-version of open and the crappy error message. Yes, this works, but it's not the kind of suggestion I'd like people to see when they find this answer using a search engine.

Comment: @innaM: I've just taken the OP's code and corrected it to worK. I've also proposed a solution with 3 arg open.